# Cannot login to SQL Server using SSMS via specific users

Tags: sql-server, azure-active-directory, ssms

I need that when I use an azure ad member to login I will have the view of all of the databases without typing the specific database I would like to connect to just like when logging as admin.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZ8Jv.png)

I have read this article but I still have difficulties:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/logins-create-manage?view=azuresql

I created the login `[SQL-READ]` which is a group I created in Azure AD for the master db as requested and also created a user in db master itself named `SQL-READ` and associated it with the login using

```sql
USE master

CREATE USER [SQL-READ] FROM LOGIN [SQL-READ];
GO
```

Furthermore I have created the same user `SQL-READ` in two more databases.

Then when I try to login with one of the accounts which are members of this SQL-READ group I get the error:

> Login failed for user "xxxxxxx" 18456.

I only manage to connect when I type the specific DB name here at the picture below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZ8Jv.png)

Comment: Have you checked the SQL Server logs? What did they state the true authentication error was?

Comment: You may check firewall or security group for your IP if you connect from external network

Comment: Currently state is state 1 which means I dont have permission.

Comment: ALL GOOD
managed to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `CREATE USER [] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER` for Azure AD logins (users and groups)